# Как вывести все таблицы из базы данных sqlite3

Tags: python, discord.py

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждую таблицу я оформляю в виде embed. В БД у меня заносится можно сказать анкета,  (2 изображение)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно вывести сразу все анкеты из бд?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
import credits
import os, sqlite3

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="*", intents = intents)
token = credits.token_bot




#member_list = [] #Список регестраций, пока оставим


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Состояние: Включён")
    global base, cur
    base = sqlite3.connect('NewWorld.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print("DataBase connected...OK")
        




@bot.command(name = 'reg')
async def reg(ctx, message, message2, message3, message4):
    #
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(name PRIMARY KEY, weapon, weapon2, armor, gs INT)'.format('data'))
    base.commit()
    warning = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name = ?'.format('data'),(ctx.author.name,)).fetchone()
    
    if warning == None:
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO data VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', (ctx.author.name, message, message2, message3, message4))
        base.commit()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Анкета ' + ctx.author.name,
            description = '**'+ctx.author.name+'**' + ' Вы успешно зарегестрировались, ваши данные: ' + '\n' + '1)Первое оружие: ' + '**'+message+'**' + '\n' + '2)Второе оружие: ' + '**'+message2+'**' + '\n' + '3)Тип брони: ' + '**'+message3+'**' + '\n' + '4)GearScore ' + '**'+str(message4)+'**')
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        
        #await ctx.send(ctx.author.name + ' Вы успешно зарегестрировались, ваши данные: ' + '\n' + '1)Первое оружие: ' + message + '\n' + '2)Второе оружие: ' + message2 + '\n' + '3)Тип брони: ' + message3 + '\n' + '4)GearScore ' + str(message4))
    
    else:
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title = 'Анкета ' + ctx.author.name,
            description = '**'+ctx.author.name+'**' + ' Вы уже зарегестрировались, ваши данные: ' + '\n' + '1)Первое оружие: ' + '**'+warning[1]+'**' + '\n' + '2)Второе оружие: ' + '**'+warning[2]+'**' + '\n' + '3)Тип брони: ' + '**'+warning[3]+'**' + '\n' + '4)GearScore ' + '**'+str(warning[4])+'**')
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        
        
        
@bot.command(name = 'update')
async def update(ctx, message, message2, message3, message4):
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(name PRIMARY KEY, weapon, weapon2, armor, gs INT)'.format('data'))
    base.commit()
    warning = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name = ?'.format('data'),(ctx.author.name,)).fetchone()

    if warning == None:
        await ctx.send("Привет, я не нашёл твоей анкеты, пожалуйста **зарегестрируйся!!!**, чтобы получить всю нужную инфу напиши ***info**")
    
    else:
        cur.execute('UPDATE data SET weapon == ?, weapon2 == ?, armor == ?, gs == ? WHERE name == ?', (message, message2, message3, message4, ctx.author.name))
        await ctx.send('**'+ctx.author.name+'**' + ' Ваша анкета успешно изменена, чтобы посмотреть вашу анкету напишите **(*show)**')
        base.commit()
        
        
        
        
    
@bot.command(name = 'delete')
async def delete(ctx):
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(name PRIMARY KEY, weapon, weapon2, armor, gs INT)'.format('data'))
    base.commit()
    warning = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name = ?'.format('data'),(ctx.author.name,)).fetchone()

    if warning == None:
        await ctx.send("Привет, я не нашёл твоей анкеты, пожалуйста **зарегестрируйся!!!**, чтобы получить всю нужную инфу напиши ***info**")
    else:
        cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM data WHERE name = '{ctx.author.name}'")
        base.commit()
        await ctx.send('**'+ctx.author.name+'**' + ' Ваша анкета успешно удалена')
        
        
        
        
    
@bot.command(name = 'show')
async def show(ctx):
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(name PRIMARY KEY, weapon, weapon2, armor, gs INT)'.format('data'))
    base.commit()
    warning = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name = ?'.format('data'),(ctx.author.name,)).fetchone()

    if warning == None:
        await ctx.send("Привет, я не нашёл твоей анкеты, пожалуйста **зарегестрируйся!!!**, чтобы получить всю нужную инфу напиши ***info**")
    else:
        
        embed = discord.Embed(
                title = 'Анкета ' + '**'+ctx.author.name+'**',
                description = '**'+ctx.author.name+'**' + ' Ваши данные: ' + '\n' + '1)Первое оружие: ' + '**'+warning[1]+'**' + '\n' + '2)Второе оружие: ' + '**'+warning[2]+'**' + '\n' + '3)Тип брони: ' + '**'+warning[3]+'**' + '\n' + '4)GearScore ' + '**'+str(warning[4])+'**')
        await ctx.send(embed = embed)
    
    


@bot.command(name = 'map')
async def map(ctx):
    await ctx.send("https://www.newworld-map.com/#/")
    
    
@bot.command(name = 'all')
async def alll(ctx):
    base.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}(name PRIMARY KEY, weapon, weapon2, armor, gs INT)'.format('data'))
    base.commit()
    warning = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM {} WHERE name = ?'.format('data'),(ctx.author.name,)).fetchall()

    if warning == None:
        await ctx.send("Привет, я не нашёл ни одной анкеты")
    else:
        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data WHERE name = 'ctx.author.name'")
        base.commit()
        await ctx.send(cur.execute)
    
@bot.command(name = 'raid')
async def send_m(ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    if member is None:
        for member in ctx.message.guild.members:
            try:
                user = await bot.fetch_user(member.id)
                embed = discord.Embed(
                   title = '_Внимание!!!_',
                   description = 'Cкоро начнётся осада, просим всех пройти регестрацию на канале клана, для того, чтобы вы и глава клана могли легко посмотреть, кто на какой роли играет, для этого в канале клана напишите команду вида: **(*reg <<Первое оружие>>, <<Второе оружие>>, <<Тип брони>>, <<Гирр скорр>>)** _Разумеется всё без скобок!_')
                await user.send(embed = embed)
                    #await user.send("Регестрируемся на осаду, указывая свою роль!!! Пример: *reg Tank")
            except:
                print('Лс закрыто')
    else:
        user = await bot.fetch_user(member.id)
        await user.send('Привет, я **Nameless bot!**, Напоминаю, что скоро начнётся осада, пройдите регестрацию в канале клана, написав команду **(*reg <<Первое оружие>>, <<Второе оружие>>, <<Тип брони>>, <<Гирр скорр>>)**')


bot.run(token)
```

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь следующим запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table'
```

В качестве ответа будут возвращены следующие столбцы:

- type
- name
- tbl_name
- rootpage
- sql